# Image display issue

Tags: python, image, tkinter, transparency, python-imaging-library

When I load a transparent image with:

```
def load_image(path):
    img = Image.open(path)
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

class Home_Screen(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.home = Tk()
        self.home.resizable(width = False,height = False)
        self.home.geometry("700x500+300+100")
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        self.images()
        Label(self.home, image = self.background).pack() # Put it in the display window
        button_instructions = Label(self.home,image = self.b_instructions).place(x = 300,y = 200)
        self.home.mainloop()

    def images(self):
        self.background = load_image("Images/night-sky.jpg")
        self.b_instructions = load_image("button_instructions.png")

    def start_game(self):
        self.home.destroy()

Home = Home_Screen()
```

I get an image with a white border around it. Does anyone know why the original transparency was not retained? If so could you please offer a solution.

[image: Image of error]

Comment: Just to be sure, are you certain the image had an alpha channel (like a PNG, and not JPEG)?

Comment: I'm certain I had a transparent .png image I checked several times

Comment: First, you have to figure out _where_ the transparency is getting lost. Get the mode of `img` to make sure it has an alpha channel, and then do `pixels=img.load()` and make sure some of the pixels actually are transparent. Try saving `img` to a new PNG file and make sure it's still transparent. If that all works, then the problem _is_ in the `PhotoImage`, or in the way you display it. But I'm betting that it isn't.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/84011326/miscellaneous/code1.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Canvas instead of Label widgets. The transparency isn't getting lost, because what you see is the background of the widget.

```
def run(self):
    img_sky = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/night-sky.jpg")
    img_button = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="button_instructions.png")
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.home, width=700, height=500)
    self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img_sky)
    self.canvas.create_image(300, 200, image=img_button)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.home.mainloop()
```